# Restore old database dump file in postgres

Tags: django, postgresql-9.3

I have dump file 'dump0', dump0 have new data in some tables whereas in my existing database I have new data and some new tables also.

Now, when I am trying to restore my'dump 0'file in existing database, it is no restoring new data of 'dump0' file.

I want both data of dump0 and existing.
If Anybody have any clue, please let me know.

I am using postgresql-9.3 and django framework.

Comment: can you update your post on how did you create dump0 file? Also what import/loaddata options have you already tried.

Comment: So you want to *merge* `dump0` into your existing database?

Comment: I created dumpfile with this command
 pg_dump database_name > dump0

I have tried 
pg_restore -d  command and psql command to restore

Comment: Yes Craig, I want to merge dump0 to my existing database.